# c++ Qt - How to check if toast notifications are enabled for my application

Tags: c++, qt, notifications, toast

I'm trying to integrate the "new" Toast Notifications of Windows 10. I am a little stuck with checking if the "Settings  > System  > Notifications & actions‌ > Get notifications from these senders" checkbox is activated for my program.
The notification is created with QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage(), since I'm working with the Qt framework on c++.
Has anyone a good idea how to go on?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As far as I know there is no Qt built-in support for it and you have to use Windows API  to do it yourself: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/ .

Comment: Alright, thank you. Thought that there was maybe an easier solution ^^